# Upstart for pydoc webserver

Tags: python, upstart

I'm trying to use `upstart` so that the `pydoc` webserver for a package I'm developing always runs. If I run it from the command line:

```
pydoc -p 7464 /some_path/my_python_package
```

it works fine, and going to `localhost:7464/my_python_package` displays the documentation. However if I put it in an upstart script, e.g.

```
start on startup
start on runlevel [2,3,4,5]
stop on runlevel [0,1,6]

script
    pydoc -p 7464 /some_path/my_python_package
end script
```

then when I open up the browser at `localhost:7464/my_python_package` I get the following:

```
no Python documentation found for 'my_python_package'
```

Note that `localhost:7464` shows all of the standard python packages as normal, so it seems like upstart isn't parsing the path correctly.

I tried using putting `export PYTHONPATH='/some_path'` in and changing the execution line to `pydoc -p 7464 $PYTHONPATH/my_python_package` but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you've specified in that job is incorrect:

- you have multiple '`start on`' stanzas.
- the last '`start on`' stanza will be considered, but yours is invalid due to using commas between runlevels (your '`stop on`' is invalid for the same reason).

You want something like this:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

script
    pydoc -p 7464 /some_path/my_python_package
end script
```

Note that with version 0.9.7 and higher of Upstart (in other words Ubuntu Natty or newer - see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/TechnicalOverviewUpstart), there is a new command called `init-checkconf` that will check your script for syntax errors. Usage is simple:

```
$ init-checkconf myjob.conf
```

Note that you must run `init-checkconf` as your user (**not** root).

Also, are you running this as a system job (job file lives in /etc/init/ ?) If so, do you really need the service to run as root? If not, see:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#run-a-job-as-a-different-user

if this is a do you really need to run that service as the root user?

Finally, I would highly recommend taking a look at the rest of the Upstart Cookbook:

- HTML version: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/
- PDF version: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/upstart_cookbook.pdf